# Mass of a hyperboloid

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

We are asked to get the mass of a hyperboloid with equation:

$$x^2+y^2-z^2 =1$$

And with density: $\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1})}$

My try:

I would first integrate on $x^2+y^2-z^2 <1$

I would get:

$$\int_0^{2pi}d\phi\int_0^{\infty}dz\int_0^{z^2+1}\frac{1}{r\sqrt{r^2+1}}dr$$

However, I don't know how to integrate the upper.

I might need to $\frac{A}{r} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{1+r^2}} =...$

But I got nowhere.

Edit: I see, that I got it wrong in the start:

[image]

Does anybody know the correct way?

Comment: Notice that : $$r^2 = z^2 + 1$$

Comment: @Essaidi Is the idea of the exercise right. Can I do this without any parametrization, the way I intended to solve it?

Comment: Take cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @Essaidi But the integral does not converge according to wolfram

Comment: For the first integral :
$$\int_0^{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}}$$

Comment: @Essaidi It also doesn't converge there. Looks like the exercise asked me to find only the mass of the surface area of the hyperboloid, I don't know..

Comment: May be you need bounds for $z$

Comment: @VLC if the question asks to find mass of $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$ (and not of $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 \leq 1$), it would most likely mean mass of the hyperboloid sheet. The integral would converge but it is going to be an elliptic integral and you may  have use an online calculator.

Comment: @MathLover Yes I think that is the case. The question was the mass of the sheet

Comment: OK pls see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seeks you to find the mass of hyperboloid sheet $x^2+y^2-z^2 =1$

$$dS = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2 + 1} ~ ~dA$$
$$= \sqrt{ \left(\frac x z \right)^2 + \left(\frac y z \right)^2 + 1} ~ ~dA$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac {2 (x^2 + y^2) - 1} {x^2 + y^2 - 1}} ~ ~dA$$

In polar coordinates,

$$ \displaystyle m = 2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_1^{\infty} \rho ~ \sqrt{\frac {2 r^2 - 1} {r^2 - 1}} ~ r ~ dr ~ d\theta$$

Please note the multiplication by $2$ as we have two identical sheets, one above xy-plane and one below.

And mass density, $ \displaystyle \rho = \frac{1}{r^2 \sqrt{1+r^2}}$

It leads to an elliptic integral and I was able to find its value using WolframAlpha.